# Making a closed question still visible to everyone due to popularity / links etc?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

An old question I've answered has been closed and for good reasons. Despite the question being bad, it gained a large amount of attention. There's a lot of upvotes. It has been favorited by quite a few users and many other questions link towards it for more information.

For these reasons I always kept an eye on the answer as it requires me to update it whenever new updates become available. I guess this is also the reason for its attention span.

Anyway, recently its "closed" information changed and showed me:

> (Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes
>   privilege)

My question is: Would it be best to make this question viewable by everyone due other questions linking towards it / its popularity?

Since most SO users do not have the required privileges to view the question, I suppose it would be an issue for them otherwise.

Also, if the community agrees it should be visible, how?

This is the question I'm talking about: [What is the difference with jquery version 1, version 2 and version 3 versions release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605120/what-is-the-difference-with-jquery-version-1-version-2-and-version-3-versions-r)

Comment: Since closed questions are visible to everyone (which you probably tested by opening link in another browser) it's unclear what you want to discuss or propose here...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The post **is** viewable by everyone.

That message you're quoting is about the close message. I.e. the instruction to

> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only...

That's why it's in a small font in that section.

If you log out and view the question you'll see what is or is not visible to everyone.

As an aside, being favourited doesn't mean very much. People do that for all sorts of reasons, sometimes to remind them to go back and vote to delete a question once it's been closed. So it isn't really a good sign that the question or its answers are useful or not.

Answer (score 2):

The question is viewable by everyone, the "viewable by" text only refers to some details in the closed box.

Notice as shown without CV privileges:
[image]
Notice as shown with CV privileges:
[image]